# Highcharts timeseries not correct plotted

Tags: highcharts

Trying to get data from a backing bean to a Highchart line chart.
Problem is, that i need a timeseries with a datetime format, but Java cannot create a JS Date Object. Even with milliseonds, the chart won't display the date.

Sample code of the backing bean:

```
final List<LineChartSeries> series = new ArrayList<>();
final LineChartSeries chartSerie = new LineChartSeries();
final SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");

LineSeries2 lineSeries = new LineSeries2();
lineSeries.setY(0.654);
lineSeries.setDate(sdf.parse("2016-01-01").getTime());
chartSerie.addData(lineSeries);

lineSeries = new LineSeries2();
lineSeries.setY(0.337);
lineSeries.setDate(sdf.parse("2016-02-01").getTime());
chartSerie.addData(lineSeries);

lineSeries = new LineSeries2();
lineSeries.setY(0.547);
lineSeries.setDate(sdf.parse("2016-03-01").getTime());
chartSerie.addData(lineSeries);

series.add(chartSerie);

chartData = new Gson().toJson(series);
```

which produces a JSON like

```
[{"data":[{"date":1451602800000,"y":0.654},{"date":1454281200000,"y":0.337},{"date":1456786800000,"y":0.547}]}]
```

My JSF Page with the Highchart (part of)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(function () {
            $('#ctrContainer').highcharts({
                chart : {
                    zoomType: 'x'
                },
                title : {
                    text : 'VTR'
                },
                xAxis: {
                    type: 'datetime'
                },
                yAxis: {
                    title: {
                      text: 'Exchange rate'
                   }
               },
               legend: {
                   enabled: false
               },
               plotOptions: {
                   area: {
                        fillColor: {
                            linearGradient: {
                                x1: 0,
                                y1: 0,
                                x2: 0,
                                y2: 1
                           },
                           stops: [
                                        [0, Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]],
                                        [1, Highcharts.Color(Highcharts.getOptions().colors[0]).setOpacity(0).get('rgba')]
                                    ]
                                },
                                marker: {
                                    radius: 2
                                },
                                lineWidth: 1,
                                states: {
                                    hover: {
                                        lineWidth: 1
                                    }
                                },
                                threshold: null
                            }
                        },
                        credits: {
                            enabled: false
                        },
                        series : $.parseJSON('#{lineChartController.chartData}')
                    });
```

The data for y-axis will be plotted correctly, but the "date" data are not correct interpreted. Any suggetions?

Comment: How is this question JSF related? I see java, js, json, but no jsf related things (besides some EL, but if that one works should be easily testable)

Comment: You are right it is not a JSF problem, my chart is only within a JSF page. So sorry for the misleading title.

Comment: Highcharts takes in integer value epoch timestamp, in milliseconds, as the datetime value. What is the output of `$.parseJSON('#{lineChartController.chartData}')`?  Are you seeing any javascript errors in the console?

Comment: The parsedJSON Object looks like "[Object { date=1451602800000,  y=0.654}, Object { date=1454281200000,  y=0.337}, Object { date=1456786800000,  y=0.547}]"

Comment: Well, i think i got the solution and find out where my misunderstanding was. My current solution creates a Number Array instead of a Map. And within the series section of chart i just fill the "data" with the result of the backing bean.